# Rail5 pdf download with Ajax Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, prawn

I have an AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
          data: {
              'inward_gate_id': document.getElementById("inward_gate_id_lorry_no").value,
              'called_by': "GENERATEPDF"
          },
          dataType: "script",
          method: 'get',
          success: function (data) {
              window.location.reload();
          }
      });
```

And in my Controller

send_data pdf.render, :filename => "report.pdf", :type=>"application/pdf", :x_sendfile => true

THe log in terminal is as follows

```
Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data report.pdf (0.5ms)
```

But the pdf is not prompted for download

Answer (score 0):

In Initializer :

```
mime type =>  allow pdf
```

and send pdf type request from ajax

(Look on [Prawn Gem For Pdf](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn) )

Comment: that has been done but pdf download is not happening

Comment: watch once prawn gem on youtube, than let me know if any problem